# Create a Setup File Windows.Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, installation

I have created a windows application setup program, it needs to have a text file in the application folder. The file is also included while creating the setup.

Once the setup successfully completes and my program tries to modify the file based on user input, its simple throwing an exception.

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium OS.

Any suggestion/help will be great to overcome this issue.

Comment: The more information you provide the better. What exception is being thrown, do you have the stack trace from the exception etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal on a Vista or Win7 machine.  Or a properly secured XP machine for that matter.  The normal install location for programs, like c:\program files\your company\your app, is read only for most users.  UAC is a counter-measure to malware messing with programs.

You'll need to store the text file into a writable location, the AppData folder.  In the Setup project, right-click "File system on target machine" and select User's Application  Data Folder.  Find that file back at runtime through Environment.GetFolderPath, passing Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData.  Or use "User's Personal Data Folder" if the user should be able to find it back easily through the Documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

What exception is being thrown? It could be a UAC issue.